# Cronjob invoking a Shell script sending empty mails

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, sendmail

I have written a shell script which checks the file system in a storage device and mails the output to specific email. When I execute it manually, it runs fine and I'm receiving email with valid contents. However, when I place it in cronjob for the same user, it is sending empty mails. I'm unable to find out what's missing. Same issue persist even if I scheduled the cronjob for root user. Below is my script :

```
$ cat qmon.sh
nas_fs -list \
| grep -v ckpt_ \
| grep -v root_ \
| awk '{print $6}' >filesystem_list
for i in `cat filesystem_list`
do
  nas_quotas -report -tree -fs $i \
  | egrep -i -B18 'mins|day|exp' >>quota_exp
done
cat quota_exp \
| mail -s "FF VNX01 Quota report" storagemgmt@mycompany.com
cat /dev/null >quota_exp
```

Comment: My suspicion is that somewhere in one of these passes or even location of filesystem_list, something depends on an environment variable that's lost. Commonly, it's ``$HOME``. Add more output along the way inside qmon.sh to help diagnose, such as before the ``for i``, do ``echo looping through list``, etc.

Comment: You don't need the backslash if you end the line with the `|`; the shell will know that the command continues on the following line, since a command cannot end with a pipe.

Comment: Don't [iterate over a file](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) with a for loop.

Comment: Is cron sending any email to the user who's running the cron jobs?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why don't you use cron's built-in mailing capabilities?
whenever a a cronjob produces any output, it will be sent to the user running the job per email.

This is also great for debugging, as it thie email might give you hints what went wrong (e.g. cron couldn't find the `qmon.sh` script; or it didn't have permissions to run it...).
So the first thing to do, is check whether the cronttab user already got some email!

Then you can use the mailing feature directly to replace your call to `mail`: simply setup the crontab user to redirect the emails to the desired address.

About the script:

- It's good practice to add a shebang to the script, so it's clear which interpreter ought to run it (`#!/bin/sh`)
- You are using a lot of temporary files for no good reason, so try using pipes instead of files:

Here's a revised version of your script:

```
$ cat qmon.sh
#!/bin/sh

nas_fs -list       \
| grep -v ckpt_    \
| grep -v root_    \
| awk '{print $6}' \
| while read fs
do
  nas_quotas -report -tree -fs "${fs}" \
  | egrep -i -B18 'mins|day|exp'
done
```

If you insist in sending the mail manually, just append `| mail -s "FF VNX01 Quota report" storagemgmt@example.com`  to the final `done`

Answer (score 0):

You're running it in a folder where you (or the user running the job) don't have permission to write to the `quota_exp` file. You could write in `/tmp`, something like

```
nas_fs -list |grep -v ckpt_ |grep -v root_ |awk '{print $6}' >/tmp/filesystem_list
for i in `cat /tmp/filesystem_list`; 
do nas_quotas -report -tree -fs $i |egrep -i -B18 'mins|day|exp' >>/tmp/quota_exp; done
cat /tmp/quota_exp  |mail -s "FF VNX01 Quota report" storagemgmt@mycompany.com
rm /tmp/quota_exp
rm /tmp/filesystem_list
```